# Upload files in Gridview and display in the same row upon completion

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to store files from a `Gridview upload` into a Folder using Asp.net.

This is my markup code to generate Upload column and The button and File Upload control.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AllowMultiple="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CommandName="Upload"  Text="OK" style=" color: #ff0000" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"/> 
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have my codebehind to handle **btnUpload_Click** as below:

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("File has been passed");
    Button bts = e.CommandSource as Button;
    Response.Write(bts.Parent.Parent.GetType().ToString());
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "upload")
    {
        return;
    }
    FileUpload fu = bts.FindControl("FileUpload4") as FileUpload;//here
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        bool upload = true;
        string fleUpload = Path.GetExtension(fu.FileName.ToString());
        if (fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xls" | fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xlsx")
        {
            fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fu.FileName.ToString()));
            string uploadedFile = (Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fu.FileName.ToString()));
            //Someting to do?...
        }
        else
        {
            upload = false;
            // Something to do?...
        }
        if (upload)
        {
            // somthing to do?...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Something to do?...
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> CS0123: No overload for 'btnUpload_Click' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandl

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 5):

You're binding both `Command` and `Click` event with your button. Your button code should be like this-

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AllowMultiple="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" CommandName="Upload"  Text="OK" style=" color: #ff0000"/> 
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and from code behind capture the command not the event. like-

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("File has been passed");
    Button bts = e.CommandSource as Button;
    Response.Write(bts.Parent.Parent.GetType().ToString());
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() != "upload")
    {
        return;
    }
    FileUpload fu = bts.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;//here
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        bool upload = true;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fleUpload = Path.GetExtension(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xls" || fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xlsx")
        {
            fu.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fileName));
            string uploadedFile = (Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadPath/" + fileName ));
            //Someting to do?...
        }
        else
        {
            upload = false;
            // Something to do?...
        }
        if (upload)
        {
            // somthing to do?...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Something to do?...
    }
}
```

above I'm assuming your gridview `ID` is `GridView1`. And another one your File Uploader control's `ID` was mismatched with your code behind. This should work.

Comment: The code executes without error but there is no response after I click Ok. I am trying to store files from a Gridview upload into a Folder using Asp.net. Maybe you could help?

Comment: did you check that your `UpLoadPath` folder exist in your project root?

Comment: Yes, it exists but there is no file uploaded inside.

Comment: hi, there was some problem in `if (fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xls" || fleUpload.Trim().ToLower() == ".xlsx")` with the operator. i edited my answer. plz try with this one.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( I just pasted your edited code and still, same result. The file that I uploaded isnt being stored to UpLoadPath folder.

Comment: hi, kindly can you try again with my updated answer?

Comment: I just did it again and still, no response. At least, Response.Write should have been called but it not. Is there something with the RowCommand? Btw, what change did you implement from the previous code?

Comment: hi, could you please put a debug point on the `GridView1_RowCommand` and see from which line the problem is creating?

Comment: When I click Ok, It doesnt even activate the Break point. Seems like something is wrong in the Markup!

Comment: what is the ID of your `griview`?